# Profiling android-ndk plain C/C++ executable

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, cyanogenmod

What is the best way to profile plain C/C++ android executables on a rooted android device?
android-ndk-profiler seems to support only ndk libraries linked to Java.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Are you building these executables yourself? Which toolchain do you use then?

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same question recently. After looking into several alternatives I decided the best option (the one I made to work, at any rate) was to build [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for Android.

[This page](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-android.html) describes how to build Valgrind for Android. See also my [GitHub project](https://github.com/xperroni/Valdroid) for a slightly different build procedure, usage notes and prebuilt Android ARMv7 binaries.

Answer (score 2):

Android NDK profiler work by GCC compiler trick so should work independent
 of JNI

This link has the details
http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/HowItWorks

As long as you can insert the startup and cleanup code into your C/C++ code it should work

You can find all the information you will need here

http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/